# parabolic subgroups and simple roots

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I'm trying to understand the link between subset of the simple roots and parabolic subgroups in the case of $\text{GL}_n$. More precisely, let $\Delta= \{\alpha_{i,i+1}\}$ be the usual set of simple roots for $\text{GL}_n$ and let $I \subset \Delta$ be a subset. What is the parabolic subgroup of $\text{GL_n}$ associated to $I$ ?

I would be very interested in a reference where this is worked out in detail (along with the theory).

Comment: Well, you should be careful. This corresponds to parabolics containing the standard Borel. They correspond to block diagonal matrices. Do you see how? If not, I can try to write something up when I get to a computer. You should look at this: http://web.stanford.edu/~makisumi/articles/reductivegroups.pdf. IIRC they discuss what you want there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I do know what a standard parabolic looks like. But what I don't know is : given the set $I$, how do I explicitely find which standard parabolic it corresponds to. I believe (because I read it somewhere ... I think :p) that if you take $I$ to be empty you obtain the Borel and if you take to be all of $\Delta$ then you obtain $\text{GL_n}$. I would like to understand these particular cases as part of a more general recipe. I have not been able to extract it from the pdf you linked to (although it looks very interesting anyway so thanks for that).

Comment: Actually I think I just convinced myself of a way to find $P$ : you take the borel and then you add entries corresponding to the transpose of you simple roots and then you take the subgroup generated by this. I imagine this is not clear at all but I don't quite see how to describe it in a better way. Now what I would like to know is how does it fit with the general picture for reductive groups.

Comment: So now that I think about it here is the general recipe corresponding to what I "described" in the case of $\text{GL_n}$. If $G$ is a reductive groupe, $B$ a borel corresponding to a basis $\Delta$ of the root system of $G$. Then the standard parabolic subgroup associated to $I\subset \Delta$ would be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $B$ and the $U_{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in I$. (here $U_{-\alpha}$ is the root subgroup of $G$ corresponding to $-\alpha$). Is that the correct definition ? Any ideas of references ?

Comment: I might be wrong but that doesn't seem to work. For example for $\textbf{GL}_3$ if you take the root $\alpha_{1,2}$ then you don't get the whole borel with what you are saying ?

Comment: You are right. I was misremembering what a parabolic subalgebra is (I was thrown off by the reference to block diagonal matrices in the first comment).